# Firefox extension that interacts with existing page content

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon

I am not a web programming expert but I would like to create a Firefox extension that rewrites pages' html and javascript code. This is a personal project so I can take my time and learn things as I go.

I haven't been able to locate a tutorial or existing extension that does both tasks.

Would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks you so much!

-CxT

Comment: Take a look at the addons greasemonkey, adblock, and (most complex) firebug. They are all open-source projects, and though it may be intimidating to look through their source code, you can also dig around in their wikis, sign up to their mailing lists, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to accomplish two different things. My advice is to learn to do both independently. For extensions, these are great tutorials:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/building_an_extension

http://www.rietta.com/firefox/Tutorial/overview.html

For "rewriting" a pages html, css, js:

http://ejohn.org/blog/hacking-digg-with-firebug-and-jquery/

Anything you don't understand in any of the tutorials, either google or ask here.

Enjoy!